# have dual-boot Ubuntu 13.10/Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-8

I have a Win 7 SP1/Ubuntu 13.10 Dual-boot, I'm so bored with Windows 7 after years and now i want to install Windows 8.1. My question is: Is it possible to install windows 8.1 to dual-boot with Ubuntu? and How ?

(I think after installing windows 8.1 Grub don't works ! is it real ? any body did it ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows stomps all over Linux when you install it, so you will need to

1. Backup your $HOME folder and all data & folders beneath it
2. Install Windows 8.1
3. Reinstall Linux
4. Copy the $HOME folder contents from backup

The comment above has much useful information, but steps 2 & 3 will take you less than an hour and are not at all complicated. As to steps 1 and 4, well, that depends on how much data you have collected.